# Application tries to launch although it is deinstalled

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd, console

In my console a message is occurring every 10 seconds. I think it's trying to launch a deinstalled application (NetDrive2):

> 18.12.15 23:55:40,047 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.bdrive.NetDrive2.nd2svc[2777]) Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /Applications/NetDrive.app/Contents/Resources: 15B42: xpcproxy + 12028 [1353][19011403-4854-3CCD-9FCF-49C36302EB40]: 0x2
>
> 18.12.15 23:57:30,155 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.bdrive.NetDrive2.nd2svc) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

I searched for files named com.apple.xpc.launchd or com.drive.NetDrive2.nd2svc, also with the Terminal, but it seems like there are no such files.

I'm running OS X 10.11.1

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Look in **~/Library/LaunchAgents** ,  **~/Library/LaunchDaemons**  , **/Library//LaunchAgents** and  **/Library/LaunchDaemons**  for files that contain _com.bdrive.NetDrive_. The first two directories are in your personal account; the other two are the Library folder at the root level of the HD. What do you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetDrive2 installer creates a launch agent plist here: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bdrive.NetDrive2.nd2svc.plist.

The file wasn't removed and is responsible for the log messages.

To get rid of the file first unload the agent with:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bdrive.NetDrive2.nd2svc
```

Then remove the file with

```
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.bdrive.NetDrive2.nd2svc.plist
```

Using the uninstaller in the mounted NetDriveInstaller_2_7_0_dev_262.dmg image instead of simply moving the app to the trash also removes the plist.

Comment: Thank you. I simply installed NetDrive again, deinstalled it with the uninstaller and it worked.